# Is there any way to force blocks created by views to display even when there is no result?

Tags: 7, views

I have similar question with "[Display a block even if it is empty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28040/display-a-block-even-if-it-is-empty)" about blocks generated with views 3.5.

Comment: Before I do a quick writeup, did you try playing with the **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR** setting?  It's under **Advanced**.  I never use the blocks that views makes, so I am not 100% sure that it works in this case.

Comment: Your comment has the value of an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views has a somewhat hidden feature for setting the behavior when you have no results.

If you edit the view and click on **Advanced**, you will see some new settings:

[image]

Click on <kbd>add</kbd> next to **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR**.  You will then get a modal with a ton of choices.  You should be able to use the textarea or markup options to plop in a &nbsp;  This should force the block to not be "empty".  You could also set a message, etc.

You can also always show the advanced options if you visit admin/structure/views/settings

I typically always set "Always show the master display" and "Always show advanced display settings".  There are some other useful settings on admin/structure/views/settings/advanced

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR, if you have a Contextual Filter, make sure that the default value is set when it is not available from the URL. Otherwise the view may be hidden.

For example, I had to update the "User Orders" view provided by Commerce and change the default value to the logged in user, instead of "hide view"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @MPD and @andrewtweber said, you can add a header and footer that will appear when there are and are not results for your view.

[image: Header/Footer for views]